# NodeJS upload file from local machine to remote server

Tags: jquery, node.js, ajax

So I had it working in my local machine, I am able to upload file from path A to B.

And the code as below

HTML

```
<form action="/fileupload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="{{_csrf}}">
   <input type="file" name="filetoupload"><br>
   <input type="submit">
 </form>
```

NodeJS

```
app.post('/fileupload', function (req, res) {
    var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
    form.parse(req, function (err, fields, files) {
      var oldpath = files.filetoupload.path;
      var newpath = 'C:/Users/MyName/uploadtesterFile/' + files.filetoupload.name;


      fs.rename(oldpath, newpath, function (err) {
        console.log(err);

        if (err) throw err;
        res.redirect(req.get('referer'));
      });
    });
 })
```

It upload the file to C:/Users/MyName/uploadtesterFile/ successfully
but when i change it to the **remote server path** it returns error, cross-device link not permitted and something....etc.

[image]

Is there's any reference? I am following the W3Cschool tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

There is a package called as [multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer). It is a middleware that handles the multipart form and uploads the data easily. It is also configurable according to our need.

```
var express = require('express')
var multer  = require('multer')
var upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' })

var app = express()

app.post('/profile', upload.single('avatar'), function (req, res, next) {
  // req.file is the `avatar` file
  // req.body will hold the text fields, if there were any
})

app.post('/photos/upload', upload.array('photos', 12), function (req, res, next) {
  // req.files is array of `photos` files
  // req.body will contain the text fields, if there were any
})

var cpUpload = upload.fields([{ name: 'avatar', maxCount: 1 }, { name: 'gallery', maxCount: 8 }])
app.post('/cool-profile', cpUpload, function (req, res, next) {
  // req.files is an object (String -> Array) where fieldname is the key, and the value is array of files
  //
  // e.g.
  //  req.files['avatar'][0] -> File
  //  req.files['gallery'] -> Array
  //
  // req.body will contain the text fields, if there were any
})
```